# ¿Qué esta mal en este código de php?

Tags: php

Germán Martínez y Lombarda Arda
El código aun me sigue enviando como resultado 0 :(
Se me paso mencionar, las variables $lado1 y $lado2 son recibidas de un input tipo number de un formulario, con ella no tengo problemas ni con la variable $medida, pues si me esta dando los valores correcto, el problema radica es con $unitario y $precio.

aquí el código PHP completo

```
    <?php
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $correo = $_POST["correo"];
    $celular = $_POST["celular"];
    $trabajo = $_POST["trabajo"];
    $tipo = $_POST["tipo"];
    $lado1 = $_POST["lado1"];
    $lado2 = $_POST["lado2"];
    $enviarcorreo = $_POST["AC"];
    $from = "citas.manosalaobra@gmail.com";
    $pagina = '<a href="http://manosalaobra.co/Contacto.html">ingresa a este link</a>';

    $medida = $lado1*$lado2;
    $unitario = 0;

if($trabajo == "Drywal"){
    if($tipo == "Muro"){
        $unitario = 300;
    }
    if($tipo == "Cielo-raso"){
        $unitario = 600;
    }
}
else{
    if($trabajo == "Pintura"){
        if($tipo == "Exterior"){
            $unitario = 200;
        }
        else{
            if($tipo == "Interior"){
                $unitario = 400;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        if($trabajo == "Puerta"){
            if($tipo == "Sencilla"){
                $unitario = 100;
            }
            else{
                if($tipo == "Doble"){
                    $unitario = 200;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            if($trabajo == "Ventana"){
                if($tipo == "Sencilla"){
                    $unitario = 50;
                }
                else{
                    if($tipo == "Puerta-Ventana"){
                        $unitario = 100;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                if($trabajo == "Pisos"){
                    if($tipo == "Ceramico"){
                        $unitario = 250;
                    }
                    else{
                        if($tipo == "Concreto"){
                            $unitario = 500;
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}

$precio = $unitario * $medida;

$headers .= "From:" . $from; 

$contenido = "
                <html>
                <head>
                    <title></tittle>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <p>Senor(a): '.$nombre.'</p>
                    <p>Para MANOS A LA OBRA es un placer poder servirle y que usted deposite en nosotros su confianza.</p>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Descripcion</th>
                            <th>Medida</th>
                            <th>Unidad</th>
                            <th>Precio u.</th>
                            <th>Precio</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>'.$trabajo.'</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>'.$tipo.'</td>
                            <td>'.$medida.'</td>
                            <td>m2</td>
                            <td>'.$unitario.'</td>
                            <td>'.$precio.'</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    Recuerde que esta cotizacion no es completa ni precisa, sino un estimado.
                    si esta interesado en una cotizacion completa y precisa puede ponerse en contacto nosotros para agendar un visita personalizada en la cual se le realizara una cotizacion mas completa y precisa.
                    Para agendar si visita '.$pagina.'
                </body>
                </html>
            ";

if($enviarcorreo == "si"){
    $envio = mail($correo, 'Su cotizacion con MANOS A LA OBRA', $contenido, $headers);

    $contenido1 = '
                Datos de cotizacion de servicio:

                Solicitante: '.$nombre.'
                Correo: '.$correo.'
                Celular: '.$celular.'
                Ciudad: '.$ciudad.'
                Solicito el servicio de: '.$servicio.'
            ';
    $envio2 = mail('citas.manosalaobra@gmail.com', 'Solicitud cotizacion', $contenido1, $headers);

    header('Location: http://manosalaobra.co/cotizacion_dada.html');
}
if($enviarcorreo == "no"){ 
    echo "<script>
                alert('No fue realizada la cotizacio');
                window.location= 'Inicio.html'
    </script>";
}

?>
```

[image: Aquí una imagen de lo que me llega al correo]

la parte que esta seleccionada en azul son los valores de $precio y $unitario, como lo ven me marca cero.

Comment: Hola Oscar y bienvenido a SOes, ¿has comprobado antes de ejecutar el if qué trae`$trabajo` y qué trae `$lado1`y `$lado2`?

Comment: No es suficiente con lo que has pasado, ahí esta todo correcto en principio. Debes comprobar que los atributos "name" de los campos del formulario coincidan con los nombres recibidos a traves de $_POST[''], comprueba que introduces Drywal en el campo del formulario con name="trabajo" y que en el campo con name="tipo" escribas algunos de los dos valores de ambos condicionales.

Comment: Podrías estar teniendo también un problema con: **$medida = $lado1*$lado2;** Yo parsearía a integer o a float **$lado1** y **$lado2** para asegurar que no estás tratando de multiplicar dos strings.

Comment: Has probado floatval($lado1); floatval($lado2)? Es posible que estés recibiendo los lados como String, y por eso no te está haciendo los cálculos correctamente además, $unitario inicializarlo arriba. teniendo en cuenta, que si no pasas por Drywal no tendrá valor esa variable $unitario

Comment: debes hacer en el inicio `$unitario = 1`

Comment: puedes imprimir el valor de trabajo? algo me dice que viene nulo o diferente de lo que esperas obtener

Comment: adicionalmente yo usuaría `strcmp`

Comment: @RuslanLópez el valor de la variable $trabajo no viene nulo, si te das cuenta en la imagen que adjunte se puede evidenciar que si imprime el valor de la variable $trabajo al igual que la de tipo.

Comment: Lo siento, no todos podemos ver las imágenes publicadas ane stackoverflow, algunos proxies restringen su carga, y tu descripción dela imágen no dice anda de eso

Answer (score 1):

El problema que que en tu código la variable **$unitario** no siempre está definida.

```
<?php 
$trabajo = $_POST["trabajo"];
$tipo = $_POST["tipo"]; 
$lado1 = $_POST["lado1"];
$lado2 = $_POST["lado2"];
$medida = $lado1*$lado2;

$unitario = 0; // Asegurarse la existencia se esa variable con un valor inicial
if($trabajo == "Drywal")
{
    if($tipo == "Muro")
    {
         $unitario = 300;
    }
    if($tipo == "Cielo-raso")
    {
        $unitario = 600;
    }
}

$precio = $unitario * $medida;
?>
```

Comment: el código aun muestra como resultado (cero)

Comment: Eso sucede si $trabajo es diference de "Drywal", y $tipo es diferente de "Muro" y de "Cielo-raso". Quizas deberias comprobar si $unitario es 0 antes de la multiplicacion

Answer (score 0):

El código como tal no tiene ningún error, he usado esta pagina para cerciorarlo https://phpcodechecker.com/. Por otro lado asegúrate que los parámetros que le llegan son correctos, yo diría que no o que al menos `$lado1` o `$lado2` están llegando como 0 y como todos sabemos, cualquier multiplicación por 0 el resultado es 0. Para asegurarte del funcionamiento, prueba a hacerlo con las variables definidas.

Por otro lado como se comenta en una respuesta  borrada de la publicación deberías declara la variable `$unitario`de manera global, ya que la usas también fuera de los if.

De tal manera yo probaría si funciona asi:

```
<?php 
$trabajo = "Drywal";
$tipo = "Muro"; // Prueba tambien con Cielo-raso 
$lado1 = 20;
$lado2 = 10;
$medida = $lado1*$lado2;

$unitario = 0; 
if($trabajo == "Drywal")
{
    if($tipo == "Muro")
    {
         $unitario = 300;
    }
    if($tipo == "Cielo-raso")
    {
        $unitario = 600;
    }
}

$precio = $unitario * $medida;
?>
```

Comment: El código aun muestra la variable $unitario y $precio como cero

Comment: @OscarDaniloRomeroCortina He probado el código en http://phptester.net/ tal y como lo he escrito, y me da `60000` de resultado.